# Trying to write a filter function with Python but got some error

Tags: python, pandas

Recently I tried to write a Python program to filter and decide the trading direction. The basic logic is if the price of that transaction is equal quoted bid price then assign it as `'s'` which represent sell. If the price of that transaction is equal quoted ask price then assign it as `'b'` which represent buy. If the price of that transaction doesn't equal either the bid price nor the ask price then compare the price with former transactions one by one. If the price is higher than the former transaction then assign it as `'b'` and if smaller then `'s'`. If cannot find the prior price that is clearly a buy or sell, then go back to the one BEFORE the last price to find it. If that doesn’t satisfy it, go back to another price. Do this until finding a clear buy or sell.

Also, since there are more than one company's data in the data set, if the last transaction's price belongs to another company, then  I assumed it was not possible and assigned it as null. I used 20 lags for the prior price to see if I could find a clear buy or sell. If I still can’t decide the trading direction after 20, then I assumed it was not possible and assigned it as null.

To do this I write the following function.

```
def bid_ask_direct(a,b,c,d,e):
if a-b == 0:
    return 's'
elif a-c == 0:
    return 'b'
else:
    for i in e:
        for j in np.arange(1,21):
            if d[i] == d[i-j]:
                if a[i] - a[i-j] > 0: 
                    return 'b'
                elif a[i] - a[i-j] < 0:
                    return 's'
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                return None
```

`df1['Trade Direct'] = bid_ask_direct(df1['Price'],df1['Bid Price'],df1['Ask Price'],df1['#RIC'],df1.index)`

When I run this function I got the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have searched a lot on this website but still can find any answers or questions that can help me.

The following this the sample data for this function.

```
          #RIC   Price  Volume  Bid Price  Ask Price
3    WTB.L   998.0   300.0      998.0      999.5
6    WTB.L   998.0   900.0      997.0      998.0
9    WTB.L   998.0    45.0      997.0      999.5
14   WTB.L   998.0   400.0      997.0      998.0
17   WTB.L   998.0    18.0      997.0      999.0
30   WTB.L   998.0  1500.0      997.5     1000.0
39   WTB.L   998.5   300.0      995.0     1000.0
59   WTB.L   999.0  1100.0      999.0     1001.0
69   WTB.L   999.5   300.0      999.5     1001.0
70   WTB.L   999.5   300.0      999.5     1001.0
94   WTB.L  1001.0   967.0     1001.0     1002.0
95   WTB.L  1001.0  1800.0     1001.0     1002.0
98   WTB.L  1001.0  1000.0     1001.0     1002.0
100  WTB.L  1001.0   118.0     1001.0     1002.0
103  WTB.L  1002.0  1600.0     1001.0     1002.0
106  WTB.L  1004.0   865.0     1001.0     1004.0
113  WTB.L  1001.0   600.0     1001.0     1004.0
126  WTB.L  1003.0   400.0     1003.0     1005.0
128  WTB.L  1003.0   945.0     1002.0     1003.0
145  WTB.L  1003.0  1200.0     1002.0     1004.0
147  WTB.L  1003.0   200.0     1003.0     1004.0
149  WTB.L  1003.0    25.0     1003.0     1004.0
151  WTB.L  1003.0    13.0     1003.0     1004.0
155  WTB.L  1002.0  1500.0     1001.0     1004.0
156  WTB.L  1002.0  2338.0     1001.0     1004.0
157  WTB.L  1002.0  1200.0     1001.0     1004.0
183  WTB.L  1004.0   300.0     1002.0     1004.0
184  WTB.L  1004.0   480.0     1002.0     1004.0
185  WTB.L  1004.0    86.0     1002.0     1004.0
188  WTB.L  1002.0   280.0     1002.0     1004.0
```

Comment: I deleted my response as I misread part of your question, I'll have it back up in a minute.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try naming your variables properly. That code is a puzzle in itself trying to understand what a,b,c,d,e,i & j mean

Comment: @Trent I thought this will be fine because I assigned values to each variable later. I will change this anyway.

Comment: @run-out Thank you and take your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to use pandas dataframe with data in this manner. You should not use straight python. If I understand your request:

I have recreated your data as follows:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
df.head()

    #RIC    Price   Volume  Bid_Price   Ask_Price
index                   
3   WTB.L   998.0   300.0   998.0   999.5
6   WTB.L   998.0   900.0   997.0   998.0
9   WTB.L   998.0   45.0    997.0   999.5
14  WTB.L   998.0   400.0   997.0   998.0
17  WTB.L   998.0   18.0    997.0   999.0
```

Insert a column to indicate buy/sell/hold:

```
df.insert(1,'Signal', '')
```

Filter for Price = Bid_Price and make 'signal' equal to 'sell'

```
df.loc[df['Price'] == df['Bid_Price'], ['Signal']] = 'sell'
```

Filter for Price = Ask_Price and make 'signal' equal to 'buy'

```
df.loc[df['Price'] == df['Ask_Price'], ['Signal']] = 'buy'
```

Results in

```
df.head()

    #RIC    Signal  Price   Volume  Bid_Price   Ask_Price
index                       
3   WTB.L   sell    998.0   300.0   998.0   999.5
6   WTB.L   buy     998.0   900.0   997.0   998.0
9   WTB.L   hold    998.0   45.0    997.0   999.5
14  WTB.L   buy     998.0   400.0   997.0   998.0
```

You indicated that if there is not a clear buy sell signal on the trading day using this method, then you would like to compare each day's price with the previous price, going back 20 days, to get a trade signal.

```
# restrict data to 20 records
df_20 = df.iloc[:20,:].copy()

# make a column with the price difference between this transaction and previous
df_20.loc[:, 'trailing_diff'] = (df_20.loc[:,'Price'] - df.loc[:,'Price'].shift(-1))

# use a mask to filter the dataframe eliminating zero values
mask = df_20['trailing_diff'] != 0
trade_signal = df_20[mask]['trailing_diff'].iloc[0]
```

Finally, use if then conditional logic to select the correct buy sell signal.

```
if df.iloc[0, :]['Signal'] != 'hold':
    signal = df.iloc[0, :]['Signal']
elif trade_signal > 0: 
    signal = 'buy'
elif trade_signal < 0: 
    signal = 'sell'
else: 
    signal = 'hold'

print('signal')
sell
```

Putting it altogether to run on a larger dataframe, with multiple securities, see below. I have not run this so as I don't have more data, hopefully there are no bugs.

```
def make_decision(df):
    df.loc[df['Price'] == df['Bid_Price'], ['Signal']] = 'sell'
    df.loc[df['Price'] == df['Ask_Price'], ['Signal']] = 'buy'

    # restrict data to 20 records
    df_20 = df.iloc[:20,:].copy()

    # make a column with the price difference between this transaction and previous
    df_20.loc[:, 'trailing_diff'] = (df_20.loc[:,'Price'] - df.loc[:,'Price'].shift(-1))

    # use a mask to filter the dataframe eliminating zero values
    mask = df_20['trailing_diff'] != 0
    trade_signal = df_20[mask]['trailing_diff'].iloc[0]

    if df.iloc[0, :]['Signal'] != 'hold':
        signal = df.iloc[0, :]['Signal']
    elif trade_signal > 0: 
        signal = 'buy'
    elif trade_signal < 0: 
        signal = 'sell'
    else: 
        signal = 'hold'
    return signal


for sec in df['#RIC'].unique():
    df_sec = df[df['#RIC'] == sec]
    print('Security', sec, '    ', make_decision(df_sec))
```

Comment: First off, thank you so much for your help. I did put them in dataframe. The reason for why I put them in one single function is because the dataset is really huge which is about 100GB. I searched on internet and someone said that it will be faster to run a function. Also, there is one more condition. When looking back 20 records, I need to make sure '#RIC' is always the same within these 20 records. How can I achieve that? Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: See the edit above, you will have to test it on your data as I don't have data to run this. Please accept the answer if this is working for you. thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the first time I ask a question on this website, how can I accept your question? Also, may I have your email address?

Comment: Glad to be of help. This community is awesome and will help you grow. No need for personal communications, I'll see you in stack overflow. Good luck.